# The type arguments for method System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.EntityTypeConfiguration<Proyect.Models.Entity>.HasMany<TTargetEntity>

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-5

I'm presenting a problem known to many, but that is bothering me and I need your help. Maybe is simple...but sometimes other eyes can see what we cannot see....

I have this method:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            modelBuilder.Entity<ValorAtributoProducto>()
                .HasMany(i => i.AtributoProducto)
                .WithRequired().WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
        }
```

This the complete error:

```
System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.EntityTypeConfiguration<Proyect.Models.ValorAtributoProducto>.HasMany<TTargetEntity>(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<Proyect.Models.ValorAtributoProducto,System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<TTargetEntity>) cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.
```

Answer (score 1):

To use **HasMany** the property needs to implement ICollecion, otherwise there is no "Many", just "One".

I really think you should use **HasRequired** instead.